# Can't add a controller in asp.net MVC3 EF code first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-phone-7, entity-framework-4

I have created a new project from template. I used windows phone cloud toolkit template which server side is a regular asp.net mvc3 project with EF 4.1 code first.

My datacontext is called SqlDataContext and has the following constructor:

```
public SqlDataContext()
            : base(ConfigReader.GetConfigValue("SqlSampleDataContextConnectionString"))
        {
        }

        public DbSet<SqlSampleData> SqlSampleData { get; set; }
```

My connection string defined in web.config as:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;User Instance=true;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\WPCloudApp26.mdf;Initial Catalog=WPCloudApp26;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have added a new model called `Report` and now i want to create new controller with the add controller wizard, using my new `Report` model and the `SqlDataContext`. when I try to create i get the following error:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'WPCloudApp1.Web.Models.Report'.
The 'SqlSampleDataContextConnectionString' setting is not available.
Parameter name: key
```

And it fails to create the new controller.

What am i doing wrong ? My background in this topic very scarce so please try to make it as simple as possible.

My Report class:

```
namespace WPCloudApp26.Web.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    // Summary:
    //     Sample Entity Framework 4.1 data class for SQL Azure.
    //     Using EF 4.1 Code-First, the database structure will be created to mirror this class properties.
    //     For more information, visit the ADO.NET Entity Framework website at http://msdn.microsoft.com/data/aa937723
    public class Report
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Edit:
I have no problem running the application, only adding a new controller.

Comment: your connection string key is "ApplicationServices", but you are using Some Other Key in the GetConfigvalue method

Comment: @Ravi when i run the application, everything works fine (i havent changed anything from the template) so i guessed that the connection string was fine

Comment: Let me show your "Report.cs" class please and after adding a new model class, you need to make a "rebuild"

WPCloudApp1==> Right-click ==> Rebuild

Comment: @Francesco I have added my report class, i have re-built the solution (and also it is running okay) but it is only the add controller wizard that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;User Instance=true;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\WPCloudApp26.mdf;Initial Catalog=WPCloudApp26;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

By:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SqlDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;User Instance=true;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\WPCloudApp26.mdf;Initial Catalog=WPCloudApp26;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The context should be the value stored in the web.config

Comment: Thanks, the application is still compiling and running okay, but the add controller wizard still gives me the same error. this "windows phone cloud application" template is really giving me a headache. documentation about it is really bad. if i could get it to work it could save me a lot of work connecting the server and the client.

Comment: Where does the problem occurs? When you right-click on your "Controllers" folder? After you click "Add -> Controller"? After the "Add Controller" prompt?

Comment: i right click on the controllers folder, add controller, choose controller with read/write... using entity framework, put in my Report model and my SqlDataContext, click okay and then i get the error

Comment: Maybe in your "Context class" add this line :

    public DbSet<Report> Report { get; set; }
and rebuild

Comment: you are right, i forgot to add it, anyway it still doesn't solve the problem, i am close to giving up, i can't find anything about this error anywhere

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no idea... But I don't understand why you use this:

public SqlDataContext()
            : base(ConfigReader.GetConfigValue("SqlSampleDataContextConnectionString"))
        {
        }
I think that the error is certainly here... Maybe you need to delete the constructor

Comment: I think ConfigReader does not work at design time. Try what happens if you use `base()`. You probably should make a parameterless constructor, and a constructor accepting a connection string.

Comment: i haven't solved it, but found a workaround: when creating the new controller, i tell it to create a new DataContext, then it works okay and creates all the views for CRUD interface. later i modify it to point to the original SqlDataContext and discards the new DataContext. so i guess the problem is like @Francesco say somewhere in the DataContext class although now everything works fine.